# NavBar using the controller for the page it is on instead of the controller set in ActionLink

Tags: model-view-controller, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am new to MVC and bootstrap and have a problem with the navbar. When I am on the home page the navbar works like it is suppose to, but when I change to a new page which uses the ActiveUser controller. The controller in the link changes from the Homecontroller to the ActiveUser controller which is not what suppose to happen. The dropdown menu part is just a test to see if it does the same and it does.

NavBar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
<div class="container">
    @Html.ActionLink("TADS", "About", "Home", new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "dropdown-item" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "dropdown-item" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "dropdown-item" })
                    </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

When on the Home Page using the home controller the navbar is converted correctly in the the browser

```
 <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/home/Index?Length=4">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/About?Length=4">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Contact?Length=4">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/home/Index?Length=4">Home</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Home/About?Length=4">About</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Home/Contact?Length=4">Contact</a>
                    </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

But when I change to Active user page the navbar is not converted correctly.  The homecontroller is replaced with the ActiveUser controller which is not what it should be doing.

```
 <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/ActiveUser/index?Length=4">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/ActiveUser/About?Length=4">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/ActiveUser/Contact?Length=4">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/ActiveUser/index?Length=4">Home</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/ActiveUser/About?Length=4">About</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/ActiveUser/Contact?Length=4">Contact</a>
                    </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to the one part of the question on Stackoverflow at these posts:
[What is the purpose of `area = "" ` in an Html.ActionLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467408/what-is-the-purpose-of-area-in-an-html-actionlink)
[How to correctly use Html.ActionLink with ASP.NET MVC 4 Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407594/how-to-correctly-use-html-actionlink-with-asp-net-mvc-4-areas)